# Text Area vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, textarea

I want to show/hide the vertical scrollbar of text area in IE when the content exceeds the height of text area. In Chrome, it only shows the scrollbar when the content exceeds the text area, else it is hidden.
I tried -ms-overflow-style:auto  and -ms-overflow-style:-ms-autohiding-scrollbar,
The first one always display the scrollber, disabled if the content is less than the text area height, but I want it hidden in that case. The second one, hides the scrollbar only until there is no focus on that text area.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please paste your code what you have tried earlier or make some fiddle to figure out what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the overflow-y to auto:

```
textarea {
    overflow-y: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style:auto;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ot9rvufa/4/

Comment: tried overflow-y:auto but in this case scrollbar never appears in IE

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: I am using IE11

Comment: Do you have any other CSS for the textarea?

Comment: Yes

width: 275px; 
margin-top: 5px;
 height: 128px; 
text-align: justify;
 display: block;
 vertical-align: top; 
word-break: break-word;

Comment: I've added your CSS and adjusted to make it work: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ot9rvufa/1/

Comment: Your solution worked, I just had to add -ms-overflow-style:auto

Comment: Great, I've added that to the answer for completeness.